# Proper way to restore user files/settings after an upgrade

Tags: restore

I would like to install a fresh ubuntu 11.04 on my home computer that has a few user accounts I will need to restore.
I currently use 'Back in Time' to back up my data.  I want to make sure everyone's account is preserved with their data and settings and was wondering if these backups will suffice?  If I restore their folders into the new 'home' folder on the fresh install, will this recreate their accounts and settings? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, `/home` should be on a separate partition. Then, when you install, specify your partitions manually. Set up your home partition to live at `/home` and make sure you *don't* format it. Then, you should have everything set up fine.

---

If you don't have a separate partition, you can use GParted to resize your partition and create a /home partition (which should usually be the largest partition) as ext4 or ext3. Then, copy everything in `/home` to the new partition and set up `fstab`.

```
# Assuming that the new partition has been created
# and formatted as ext4 and is known as /dev/sda2.
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo cp -av /home/* /mnt  # The -a option is really important here; if you forget it, things will break.

# Verify that everything was copied correctly; then...
cd /home  # Make sure that nothing is using your home directory--not even the current working directory.
sudo rm -r /home/*
sudo umount /mnt && sudo mount /dev/sda2 /home
```

Then, add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda2    /home    ext4    relatime    0 2
```